# Is there a way to add playback buttons for my app inside Google Maps "driving mode"?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently came across this Google Maps functionality, as I don't use the app very frequently, and I wanted to know if is it possible to add support for my app as to control it from there. I have a React Native app which doesn't have anything music-related, but it makes use of Google Maps, it launches it with a route defined from my app as to use the GPS mode, what I want to do is for my app to appear with its icon and a button which takes the user back to my app, I searched for a library but I didn't find anything, I think that the only way is to do it natively, but first I want to know if it is possible.

[I'm referring to this functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qajvr.jpg)

I tried looking up for React Native libraries and info about ways to making it natively, but unfortunately I didn't find any info at all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that the Google Maps API and the Google Maps App are different platforms, and from what I know, the functionality you have pointed out is a built in feature of the Google Maps App itself. And yes, I guess you would have to make your own if you want that functionality.